# TFS conflict in file suddenly only lets one keep local or server version no mergetool available

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I'm using tfs to version control a visual studio 2013-solution.

So far I didn't run into many problems but all of a sudden for one of the files which is changed on an almost hourly base the option to use the mergetool on a conflict disappeared and only "keep local" version and "keep server version" are available.

When it first appeared I thought it were just too many changes for the mergetool but then it was with only 1 line inserted the same phenomenon. For all other files the mergetool appears as a possibility though only this one file is excempt there.

My question here is what can have caused this all of a sudden (after 2 months of working with that solution and also that file) and how can this be changed? (it is quite unnerving if one has to copy the local file into notepad, then say keep server version and copy 1-3 lines back into the file which are now missing and that 8x per day)

Comment: There is no Visual Studio 2014.

Comment: tnx. overlooked the 14, 13 error^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first please lets clarify a few details: what version of tfs are you using, what version of vs (2014 does not sound right).
Now let me try to guess what happenned:

- right click on it in source control explorer and check if its marked as a binary file. You need to change it to text encoding to allow merges.
- another idea is that unexpected change was checked in add over delete maybe. You can check it in history in resolve dialog.

Comment: the next possibility is that your TFS administrator changed the source control types merge behaviour or the overall "allow multiple checkout" behaviour in `Team - Team Project Settings - Source Control` or `Team - Team Project Collection Settings - Source Control`

Comment: The file in question is a .cs file and shown as every other .cs file. Additionally it is the only file where the problem occurs. Thus if any other file is checked out by multiple parts of the team we get the merge option if there are any conflicts. Then conflicts where the unexpected behaviour occurs are all edit conflicts (partly 1 single line more in the least case) and like I said the strange behaviour only occurs in that single .cs file. As for TFS version: TFS 2013 (Visual Studio 2014)

Comment: I believe you can mark specific file as binary. Please check that in sc Explorer like i described

Comment: Yepp you were correct there with teh binary file. Tnx that helped there!